# How to create a shell script to read and write whenever a new line is written into a log file?

Tags: bash, shell

"I have a shell script which filters certain keywords from various logs and copies these lines into a new file. Now the task is I have to push these logs in live towards elasticsearch. But when done so, I'm getting duplicate entries. I need a shell script which can filter an push only the new lines written. Can anyone please help me out. Thanks in advance"

Comment: Try `tail -f logfile`

Comment: Why not use filebeat and the monitoring in that? https://discuss.elastic.co/t/first-level-filtering-with-filebeat/92212 as an example. I don't understand how you're getting duplicates either.

Comment: Tried tail -f and tail -n but both of these are bringing up duplicate entries in the output and way r filter which I can use to apply to avoid the duplicates

Comment: @bob dylan I am using fluentd as log scrapper instead of logstash, Does filebeat and fluentd go well together.

Comment: https://docs.fluentd.org/filter Just use the filter then. As I said - I'm not sure how you're getting duplicates as it should only read new lines (or whole files) anyway.

Comment: @bobdylan K will try this now

Answer (score 0):

```
tail -f logFile | uniq
```

**tail -f** follows updates and **uniq** reduces multiple identical lines to one line.

Comment: Presuming this is an actual log file, `uniq` would be superfluous due to the timestamp.